# Label above node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

I wish to add a label above a node that already contains a label.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
    \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
    \node (b) at (2,0) {b};
    \draw[->] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The markup above will give me this:

[image: tikzpicture1]

But I want something like this:

[image: tikz2]

Is there any easy way to solve this? I am **not** looking for solutions using `\tikzlibrary{background}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try: `\node (a) [label=above:{1/16}] at (0,0) {a};` BTW, next time please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and the packages you loaded.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Actually, tikz nodes have text inside and labels outside:

[image: label]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
    \node[label={\small 1/16}] (a) at (0,0) {a};
    \node (b) at (2,0) {b};
    \draw[->] (a) to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me noted: since `label` is node, its features is influenced by options determined in `every node` style. To see this, change `every node/.style={draw=black,circle}` to `every node/.style={draw, red,circle}`  ... Therefore it is sensible in similar cases to define labels' style with something as `every label/.append style={rectangle, font=\small}`.

Comment: Excellent.  We can also use `\node[label={[xshift=1em, yshift=-1em] XYZ}]` to shift the label positions.

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-node`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\def\labelSep{\fpeval{28.75*\radius+3.375}} % found by experimenting

% parameters
\def\arrowLength{1.8}
\def\radius{0.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{4*\radius+\arrowLength},\fpeval{2*\radius+0.35})
% change `0.35` in the calculation of the height of the bounding box
% according to the contents on top of the node
  \cnode(\radius,\radius){\radius}{A}
  \rput(A){a}
  \cnode(\fpeval{3*\radius+\arrowLength},\radius){\radius}{B}
  \rput(B){b}
  \ncline{->}{A}{B}
  \uput{\labelSep pt}[90](A){\small\texttt{1/16}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that all you have to do is choose the values of the parameters and the drawing (including the bounding box) will be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: `\ncline{->}{A}{B}`