# Having issue with node label when using TikZ inside beamer class

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, labels

I am drawing a small graph using `TikZ` and would like to show the name of the node inside the node. Based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216401/label-above-node-in-tikz/216418), I follow the same logic. Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,minimum size=2mm ,every node/.style={circle,fill=black}, text=white, minimum size=0.45 cm]
  \node (n1)[color= red] at (0,-3) {};
  \node (n2) at (0,3) {};
  \node (n3) at (3,6) {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3}
    \draw[thick](\from) -- (\to);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, when I want to show the node labels, I place my text inside `{}` as `\node (n1)[color= red] at (0,-3) {1};`. This line makes my node larger rather than printing the node label. I was wondering what I might be doing wrong. 
Also, my intention is to show the labels within the node (i.e., inside the circle).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see why your red node grows, let's make the text visible by adding `text=black`. (Recall that `color=red` also changes the text color.)

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,minimum size=2mm ,every
     node/.style={circle,fill=black},text=white,minimum size=0.45 cm]
  \node (n1)[color= red,text=black] at (0,-3) {1};
  \node (n2) at (0,3) {};
  \node (n3) at (3,6) {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3}
    \draw[thick](\from) -- (\to);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The circle has grown to host the `1`.

If you want to label the node, use `label`.

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, ,nodes={circle,fill=black,minimum size=3mm}, 
every label/.append style={rectangle,text=black},text=white]
  \node (n1)[color= red,label=right:1] at (0,-3) {};
  \node (n2) at (0,3) {};
  \node (n3) at (3,6) {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3}
    \draw[thick](\from) -- (\to);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the nodes all the same size, add some `text width` and `text height`. Also use `fill=red` instead of `color=red` to only change the fill color.

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,minimum size=2mm ,every
     node/.style={circle,fill=black,text width={width("1")},
        text height={height("1")}},text=white]
  \node (n1)[fill= red] at (0,-3) {1};
  \node (n2) at (0,3) {};
  \node (n3) at (3,6) {};
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3}
    \draw[thick](\from) -- (\to);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I actually need to show the labels inside each node.

Comment: @whitepanda Then you need `text=black` (or any other color that is visible when surrounded by red).

Comment: Thanks! How can I define it globally? I will have several nodes.

Comment: @whitepanda Just use `fill=red` instead of `color=red`. Then you will not overrule the fill color. I added an example of that type, which also makes sure that all the nodes have the same size.

Comment: It should of course read "Then you will not overrule the *text* color."...